# Display all posts from database in row

Tags: php, html

I was trying to echo out everything on my posts table in the databases but only one seems to be displaying and if i try to duplicate the code it repeats only one of  1 id in the posts table

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];
        $product_category_id = $row['product_category_id'];
        $product_name = $row['product_name'];
        $product_price = $row['product_price'];
        $product_details = $row['product_details'];
        $product_image = $row['product_image'];
?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="single_special_cource">
                <img width="360px" height="313px" src="img/<?php echo $product_image; ?>" class="special_img" alt="">
                <div class="special_cource_text">
                    <a href="course-details.php?p_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>" class="btn_4">
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$product_category_id}";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
            echo $cat_title;
        }
?>
                    </a>
                    <h4>‎<?php echo $product_price; ?></h4>
                    <a href="course-details.php?p_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                        <h3><?php echo $product_name; ?> </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p><?php echo $product_details; ?> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You are overwriting your variables in the inner loop (most importantly `$result`). And you probably want a `JOIN` to get all results in 1 query.

Comment: I would start separating the layout from the business logic

Comment: It will be better if you select data to JOIN table. Follow the link to know it: https://datainflow.com/question/join-two-tables-php/

Answer (score 0):

try to change while loop to

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row) {
   // code here
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables used in the main while loop are over riding your row and query. Change the inner loops variable names

```
<?php 
$categoryQ = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$product_category_id}";
$categoryRes = mysqli_query($connection, $categoryQ); 
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categoryRes)) { 
  $cat_id = $row2['cat_id']; 
  $cat_title = $row2['cat_title']; 
  echo $cat_title; 
}
?>
```

For example